# ASP.NET MVC Ajax - UpdateTargetId means two divs with same Id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Suppose this is partialview:

```
<div id = "DivTarget">
... some Ajax form
... other stuff
</div>
```

If I submit the form using Ajax and set the updateTargetId to be "DivTarget", then that means after the response, I'll have two div's with the same id: DivTarget.

The only workaround I can think of is on the page referencing the partialview, wrap the partialview with the div that's supposed to be the updatetargetid. That is such a pain, because it's partialview's job. Main page shouldn't be concerned with it.

Answer (score 0):

The div should not be in the partial. It should be in the view rendering this partial:

```
<div id="DivTarget">
    @Html.Partial("_foo")
</div>
```

and in the partial:

```
... some Ajax form with UpdateTargetId set to DivTarget
... other stuff
```

Comment: but isn't it a pain to remember to add the div always? while for partialview, it's right there and then, and you just can't forget it. Plus what if the partial view is being accessed by multiple views?

Comment: @progtick, no, for me it isn't a pain. And even if I forget it, FireBug tells me immediately.